# get html with css using only javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get all html in a div with the css. Most of the css is in classes in an external css file.

```
  document.getElementById("mydiv")
```

this only gives me the html with the inline css. 
Is it even possible to somehow render the page with the css as inline even though it comes from css-files?

Answer (score 1):

How about using this function here, sourced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5830517/2483271):

```
function css(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
        for (var i in css) {
            if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof css == "string") {
        css = css.split("; ");
        for (var i in css) {
            var l = css[i].split(": ");
            s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

As a use case:

```
var style = css($("#myDiv")); // Retrieve all styles from $("#myDiv")
$("#elementToPutStyleInto").css(style); // Put those styles onto another element.
```

Then, to get each element within the `<div>`:

```
// .find('*') gets every child element.
$('#myDiv').find('*').each(function() {
    // Do stuff here to each element using `this`
    console.log(this);
});
```

Combine the two to get the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get another html document in a div Use iframe

```
<iframe src="one.htm" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: what do you mean by get another html document? I just want the html code as a string with css so i can pass it down to my c# controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible  solution from the MDN here is the article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

and here the code.

```js
  function getTheStyle(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("elem-container");
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = theCSSprop;
   }
  getTheStyle();
```

```css
 #elem-container{
   position: absolute;
   left:     100px;
   top:      200px;
   height:   100px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="elem-container">dummy</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

With this you could iterate through all elements and Properties. It is not the whole code you might need, but a good starting point.